# ORA-00903: invalid table name. I don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a table but i get this error.
I know the table does not exists.

```
create table Comenzi_Livrare
(ID_Comanda number(8),
CUI_Mag number(8),
ID_Client number(8),
data_comanda date,
constraint pk_ID_COMANDA primary key (ID_comanda),
constraint fk_cui_mag foreign key (CUI_Mag) references (Magazin),
constraint fk_ID_CLIENT foreign key (ID_Client) references (Clienti));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify both the table name and column name in the parent table of the foreign key relationships.

As currently written, `Magazin` and `Clienti` are being interpreted as column names with a missing table name for each.

I don't know the column names in the parent tables, but this example should help you:

```
create table Comenzi_Livrare
(
ID_Comanda number(8),
CUI_Mag number(8),
ID_Client number(8),
data_comanda date,
constraint pk_ID_COMANDA primary key (ID_comanda),
constraint fk_cui_mag foreign key (CUI_Mag) references Magazin (CUI),
constraint fk_ID_CLIENT foreign key (ID_Client) references Clienti (ID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if tables exist in database: `Magazin` and `Clienti`
This error occurs because of these tables are unknown to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the word "number" to int.

```
create table Comenzi_Livrare
(ID_Comanda int(8),
CUI_Mag int(8),
ID_Client int(8),
data_comanda date,
constraint pk_ID_COMANDA primary key (ID_comanda),
constraint fk_cui_mag foreign key (CUI_Mag) references (Magazin),
constraint fk_ID_CLIENT foreign key (ID_Client) references (Clienti));
```

Answer (score 0):

you're missing table name on fk_cui_mag constraint

it should be:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
```